# htaccess Redirect Wildcard Subdomains to https (Including www)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently my htaccess file redirects non-https requests for all of my subdomains to https... except for www requests. I.e. `http://subdomain.example.com` gets redirected to `https://subdomain.example.com` (this is correct) but `www.subdomain.example.com` get redirected to `https://www.subdomain.example.com` (not correct). Here's my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Trying to redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Read the three line under the comment `# Trying to redirect to https` If HTTPS if off and we are not serving on port 443, redirect to the host (everything between http:// and the trailing / after .com). You are literally redirecting everything to HTTPS using whatever they put for the host.

Comment: That's correct, but that doesn't answer my question. How would I modify this code to redirect www to https as well? I'm a beginner when it comes to htaccess stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.|)(.+\.example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: With this change `subdomain.example.com` gets redirected to `https://www.subdomain.example.com` and `www.subdomain.example.com` is still redirected to `https://www.subdomain.example.com.

Comment: @sterfry68 As you can see, [it works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pxWHE.png)

Comment: @sterfry68 have you cleared your browser's cache? Those rules work fine.